# Why my ng2-chart data isn't scaled properly?

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I've some data coming from a service that gets displayed in an `ng2-chart`.

It's a dummy chart that display some fake data for the moment.

Here is the HTML side:

```
          <canvas
             baseChart
             [datasets]="[getDataSet(currentTest.results['cpu'])]"
             [options]="timeChartOptions"
             chartType="line"
          >
          </canvas>
```

here is the `timeChartOptions`:

```
   public timeChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
      scales: {
         xAxes: [
            {
               type: 'time',
               time: {
                  unit: 'second',
               },
            },
         ],
      },
   };
```

and here is how I format the data(i've only one serie):

```
   public getDataSet(testResult: TestResult): ChartDataSets | undefined {
      if (testResult) {
         return {
            data: testResult.indexes.map((x, index) => ({ x: +x, y: testResult.values[index] })),
            label: testResult.name,
         };
      }
      return undefined;
   }
}
```

I don't think that the way I transform my serie is relevant because I see the data with the correct order, but when I display the chart:

1. It quickly blink with the 100% correct display
2. Then the data doesn't have the correct amplitude(if it helps, my data have amplitude between 1 and 22).

Here is a small video of what I see when I refresh the page:
https://www.screencast.com/t/LzUdPK4mu

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!

The issue was that I was using a function to compute the data set for ng-charts. When I did put a `console.log`, I realized that this function get called a lot, so basically the chart was getting new data set in a loop, and I guess there is some kind of start animation.